# Testing Jenkins "Code Coverage API Plugin"

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, I have installed "Code Coverage API Plugin" in Jenkins, now want to test it.
I am trying to do steps from this page https://plugins.jenkins.io/code-coverage-api/.

But I did not understand where to put XML files from points 1 and 2.

Can anybody help me, please?

[image: Pagescreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The tags present in the images are the plugins that will be added in the pom.xml of the application. By running mvn clean package cobertura will generate a report based on the formats provided, xml or html.

If the code is checked out to the job and after running "mvn clean package" cobertura report will be generated under project workspace target/site/cobertura
The xml path is provided to code coverage api to provide the graphical representation.

Jacaco is preferred for java versions >=8 whereas cobertura doesn't cover for java8 based functionalities.